# Boletos bancário: Pegar valor corretamente pela linha digitável

Tags: javascript

Preciso capturar o valor correto de boletos bancários através da linha digitável, mas não estou conseguindo.

**Aqui é como faço:**

```
var linha = "34191.75009 01544.841545 78554.760005 4 25230000093423";

var valor = linha.substring(45,54).replace(/^0+/, ''); // Retira todos os zeros à esquerda

var valor_final = valor.substring(0,3) + "," + valor.substring(4,5); // 934,23
```

Até aqui tudo bem, mas se o valor for menor que `100` ou maior que `999`, como capturar corretamente?

Existe alguma outra forma para capturar corretamente a parte à esquerda da vírgula independente de quantidade de casas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
var linha = "34191.75009 01544.841545 78554.760005 4 25230000000883";

var valor = parseFloat(linha.substring(linha.length - 10, linha.length)).toString() // uso parseFloat parar retirar os zeros e toString para converter novamente em string

if (valor.length == 2) { // verifica se linha tem apenas 2 caracteres
  var valor_final = "0," + valor; // coloca o zero na frente
}else if (valor.length == 1) { // verifica se linha tem apenas 1 caractere
  var valor_final = "0,0" + valor; // coloca o 0,0 na frente
} else { 
  // qualquer outro valor ganha a mesma formatação
  var valor_final = valor.substring(0, valor.length -2) + "," + valor.substring(valor.length -2, valor.length);
}

console.log(valor_final)
```